# Props do not affected to child after second click

Tags: vue.js

I wrote simple App https://jsfiddle.net/9tvekf26/
Children component getting `props: ['isActive'],`
and than change it's value to make modal window visible:

```
data: function()
{
  return {
    isActive: this.isActive // value from props
  }
},
```

In `closeModalWindow` I am changing flag and emitting message to parent:

```
  closeModalWindow: function()
  {
    this.isActive = false;
    bus.$emit('my-event', this.isActive)
    console.log("Children Window closed: ", this.isActive)
  },
```

In parent I am listening message and change is's status:

```
  mounted () {
    bus.$on('my-event', function (isActive) 
    {
      this.isActive = isActive
      console.log("Parent listened: ", this.isActive)
    });
  }
```

The problem that apps stops work after first appear of modal window.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: 1. removed the `bus.on('my-event')` inside child component(name='modal-notifications'), 2, change data property=isActive to isInternalActive, you can not use same name for prop and data property. you should see the error when open the browser console. 3, inside child component, add one watch to detect prop=isActive, if it is changed, assign latest value to data property=isInternalActive

Comment: 4. the modal didn't popup for second click is caused by the context is not Vue instance inside `bus.$on('my-event', function () {})`, use arrow instead like  `bus.$on('my-event', () => {})`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the bus variable. I think it's not a good practice to use the global Vue object.
It's preferable to use `this.` of the component.

I change little bite your code:

1. From the child component I emit an event: `this.$emit(...)` instead of `bus.$emit(...)`
2. The parent component subscribe to the event of the child: `@my-event="[method-name]"`
3. I set the new value of `isActive` in the method

The new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tvekf26/17/